# ValueError в JSON файле

Tags: python, json

Я пытаюсь открыть json файл в реализации онтологии (работает как protege) и оно выдает `ValueError`, не объясняя дальше. Я не хочу трогать код, потому что он работал раньше и я думаю что проблема в json файле - я раньше таких не писал и не уверен в своих способностях.

```json
{
    "HierarchyName": "Студия",
    "Structure": [
        {
            "Name": "Студия звукозаписи",
            "Attributes": {},
            "Parent": null,
            "Instances": []
        },
        {
            "Name": "Отдел кадров",
            "Attributes": {},
            "Parent": "Студия звукозаписи",
            "Instances": []
        },
        {
            "Name": "Артисты",
            "Attributes": {
                "Зарплата": {
                    "type": "NUM_SINGLE"
                },
                "InstanceName": {
                    "type": "STR_SINGLE"
                },
                "Дата рождения": {
                    "type": "STR_SINGLE"
                },
                "Должность": {
                    "type": "STR_SINGLE"
                }
            },
            "Parent": "Отдел кадров",
            "Instances": []
        },
        {
            "Name": "Звуковики",
            "Attributes": {
                "Зарплата": {
                    "type": "NUM_SINGLE"
                },
                "InstanceName": {
                    "type": "STR_SINGLE"
                },
                "Дата рождения": {
                    "type": "STR_SINGLE"
                },
                "Должность": {
                    "type": "STR_SINGLE"
                }
            },
            "Parent": "Отдел кадров",
            "Instances": []
        },
        {
            "Name": "Бухгалтерия",
            "Attributes": {
                "Зарплата": {
                    "type": "NUM_SINGLE"
                },
                "InstanceName": {
                    "type": "STR_SINGLE"
                },
                "Дата рождения": {
                    "type": "STR_SINGLE"
                },
                "Должность": {
                    "type": "STR_SINGLE"
                }
            },
            "Parent": "Отдел кадров",
            "Instances": []
        },
        {
            "Name": "Руководство",
            "Attributes": {
                "Зарплата": {
                    "type": "NUM_SINGLE"
                },
                "InstanceName": {
                    "type": "STR_SINGLE"
                },
                "Дата рождения": {
                    "type": "STR_SINGLE"
                },
                "Должность": {
                    "type": "STR_SINGLE"
                }
            },
            "Parent": "Отдел кадров",
            "Instances": []
        },
        {
            "Name": "Директор",
            "Attributes": {},
            "Parent": "Студия звукозаписи",
            "Instances": []
        },
        {
            "Name": "Аранжировщик",
            "Attributes": {
                "Зарплата": {
                    "type": "NUM_SINGLE"
                },
                "InstanceName": {
                    "type": "STR_SINGLE"
                },
                "Дата рождения": {
                    "type": "STR_SINGLE"
                }
            },
            "Parent": "Директор",
            "Instances": []
        },
        {
            "Name": "Звукорежисер",
            "Attributes": {
                "Зарплата": {
                    "type": "NUM_SINGLE"
                },
                "InstanceName": {
                    "type": "STR_SINGLE"
                },
                "Дата рождения": {
                    "type": "STR_SINGLE"
                }
            },
            "Parent": "Директор",
            "Instances": []
        },
        {
            "Name": "Композитор",
            "Attributes": {
                "Зарплата": {
                    "type": "NUM_SINGLE"
                },
                "InstanceName": {
                    "type": "STR_SINGLE"
                },
                "Дата рождения": {
                    "type": "STR_SINGLE"
                }
            },
            "Parent": "Директор",
            "Instances": []
        },
        {
            "Name": "Администратор",
            "Attributes": {
                "Зарплата": {
                    "type": "NUM_SINGLE"
                },
                "InstanceName": {
                    "type": "STR_SINGLE"
                },
                "Дата рождения": {
                    "type": "STR_SINGLE"
                }
            },
            "Parent": "Директор",
            "Instances": []
        },
        {
            "Name": "Исполнители",
            "Attributes": {
                "Зарплата": {
                    "type": "NUM_SINGLE"
                },
                "InstanceName": {
                    "type": "STR_SINGLE"
                },
                "Дата рождения": {
                    "type": "STR_SINGLE"
                }
            },
            "Parent": "Директор",
            "Instances": []
        },
        {
            "Name": "Поэт",
            "Attributes": {
                "Зарплата": {
                    "type": "NUM_SINGLE"
                },
                "InstanceName": {
                    "type": "STR_SINGLE"
                },
                "Дата рождения": {
                    "type": "STR_SINGLE"
                }
            },
            "Parent": "Директор",
            "Instances": []
        },
        {
            "Name": "Бухгалтер",
            "Attributes": {
                "Зарплата": {
                    "type": "NUM_SINGLE"
                },
                "InstanceName": {
                    "type": "STR_SINGLE"
                },
                "Дата рождения": {
                    "type": "STR_SINGLE"
                }
            },
            "Parent": "Директор",
            "Instances": []
        }
    ],
    "Instances": [
        {
            "ClassName": "Артисты",
            "Values": {
                "InstanceName": "Ребек Ф. А.",
                "Зарплата": 70000,
                "Дата рождения": "15.06.2001",
                "Должность": "Композитор"
            }
        },
        {
            "ClassName": "Артисты",
            "Values": {
                "InstanceName": "Стонкс А. А.",
                "Зарплата": 20000,
                "Дата рождения": "15.06.2000",
                "Должность": "Чтец"
            }
        },
        {
            "ClassName": "Артисты",
            "Values": {
                "InstanceName": "Джордан М. А.",
                "Зарплата": 50000,
                "Дата рождения": "15.06.1999",
                "Должность": "Поэт"
            }
        },
        {
            "ClassName": "Звуковики",
            "Values": {
                "InstanceName": "Рейнер Р. А.",
                "Зарплата": 55000,
                "Дата рождения": "15.03.1999",
                "Должность": "звукорежсер"
            }
        },
        {
            "ClassName": "Звуковики",
            "Values": {
                "InstanceName": "Мелон Н. О.",
                "Зарплата": 30000,
                "Дата рождения": "15.09.2001",
                "Должность": "Композитор"
            }
        },
        {
            "ClassName": "Бухгалтерия",
            "Values": {
                "InstanceName": "Стокер Б.Д.",
                "Зарплата": 70000,
                "Дата рождения": "15.09.2001",
                "Должность": "Бухгалтер"
            }
        },
        {
            "ClassName": "Руководство",
            "Values": {
                "InstanceName": "Аблер Ф.А.",
                "Зарплата": 100000,
                "Дата рождения": "15.12.2001",
                "Должность": "Директор"
            }
        },
        {
            "ClassName": "Руководство",
            "Values": {
                "InstanceName": "Аарон П.В.",
                "Зарплата": 60000,
                "Дата рождения": "15.07.2002",
                "Должность": "Администратор"
            }
        },
        {
            "ClassName": "Исплнители",
            "Values": {
                "InstanceName": "Ребек Ф. А.",
                "Зарплата": 70000,
                "Дата рождения": "15.06.2001"
            }
        },
        {
            "ClassName": "Исплнители",
            "Values": {
                "InstanceName": "Стонкс А. А.",
                "Зарплата": 20000,
                "Дата рождения": "15.06.2000"
            }
        },
        {
            "ClassName": "Исплнители",
            "Values": {
                "InstanceName": "Джордан М. А.",
                "Зарплата": 50000,
                "Дата рождения": "15.06.1999"
            }
        },
        {
            "ClassName": "Аранжировщик",
            "Values": {
                "InstanceName": "Рейнер Р. А.",
                "Зарплата": 55000,
                "Дата рождения": "15.03.1999"
            }
        },
        {
            "ClassName": "Звукорежисер",
            "Values": {
                "InstanceName": "Мелон Н. О.",
                "Зарплата": 30000,
                "Дата рождения": "15.09.2001"
            }
        },
        {
            "ClassName": "Композитор",
            "Values": {
                "InstanceName": "Стокер Б.Д.",
                "Зарплата": 70000,
                "Дата рождения": "15.09.2001"
            }
        },
        {
            "ClassName": "Администратор",
            "Values": {
                "InstanceName": "Аблер Ф.А.",
                "Зарплата": 100000,
                "Дата рождения": "15.12.2001"
            }
        },
        {
            "ClassName": "Бухгалтер",
            "Values": {
                "InstanceName": "Аарон П.В.",
                "Зарплата": 60000,
                "Дата рождения": "15.07.2002"
            }
        },
        {
            "ClassName": "Поэт",
            "Values": {
                "InstanceName": "Димп П.В.",
                "Зарплата": 30000,
                "Дата рождения": "14.07.2002"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Queries": [
        {
            "In": "Студия звукозаписи",
            "Attribute": "Зарплата",
            "Relation": ">=",
            "Value": 30000
        },
        {
            "In": "Отдел кадров",
            "Attribute": "Дата рождения",
            "Relation": "=",
            "Value": "15.06.2001"
        },
        {
            "In": "Директор",
            "Attribute": "InstanceName",
            "Relation": "=",
            "Value": "Стокер Б.Д."
        }
    ]
}
```

Ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Диаграмма для онтологии:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал переписывать файл - у меня там были ошибки, но думаю они все еще есть и я засчет неопытности их не заметил

прикрепляю фрагмент кода:

```
    def parse_from_json(self, filename):
    try:
        with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as data:
            parsed_json = json.load(data)
            self.name = parsed_json["HierarchyName"]
            hier_data = parsed_json["Structure"]
            instances_data = parsed_json["Instances"]
            for classdata in hier_data:
                cl = HClass(classdata["Name"])
                # parse attributes
                for name, batch in classdata["Attributes"].items():
                    cl.add_atr(name, batch["type"])
                    # add into hierarchy
                if self.root_class is None and classdata["Parent"] is None:
                    self.root_class = cl
                else:
                    parent = self.find_class(classdata["Parent"])
                    if parent is None:
                        del self.root_class
                        raise ValueError(cl.name + " has no parent in hierarchy!")
                    parent.subclasses.append(cl)
            for instance in instances_data:
                cl = self.find_class(instance["ClassName"])
                if cl is None:
                    raise ValueError
                inst_values = instance["Values"]
                inst_name = inst_values["InstanceName"]
                del inst_values["InstanceName"]
                cl.create_instance(inst_name, inst_values)
            if "Queries" in parsed_json:
                self._queries = parsed_json["Queries"]
    except ValueError as err:
            if self.root_class:
                del self.root_class # clean tree before exiting
            raise err
```

Comment: Загружаются эти данные как `JSON` нормально. А как вы собственно парсите этот json - непонятно, кода нет.

Comment: Почитайте документацию Почему возникает данная ошибка вот документация по этому https://www.codecamp.ru/blog/valueerror-trailing-data/

Comment: @webdeveloper 1 - блог пост по ссылке не является документацией. 2 - описанная в посте по ссылке проблема не та же, что в вопросе здесь.